# ComplexHeatmap: increase size of labels of top annotation

Tags: heatmap, rna-seq, complexheatmap

any ideas on how to increase the size of the y-axis of the boxplot (-5, 0, 5) or top notation of my heatmaps?

I appreciate any help....

```
ha <- HeatmapAnnotation(summary = anno_summary(gp = gpar(fill = 3), 
                                               height = unit(2, "cm")), annotation_name_gp = gpar(fontsize = 12), labels_gp = gpar(fontsize = 12))                                               
                                               
#annotation_label_gp= gpar(fontsize = 20) label_gp = gpar(fontsize = 20))                                                       
                                               
h1<- Heatmap(mat.scaled, cluster_rows = F, name="Z-score", cluster_columns = T, col= col_fun, width = ncol(mat.scaled)*unit(10.5, "mm"), height = nrow(mat.scaled)*unit(10.5, "mm"), show_column_names = F, show_column_dend = T, top_annotation=colAnn) 


#Para separar bloques: rect_gp = gpar(col = "white", lwd = 0.08)
#Para dividir columnas: column_km = 2 (k-means clustering)
            
h2 <- Heatmap(l2_val, row_labels = df.top$symbol, 
            cluster_rows = F, name="LFC", top_annotation = Upset(ha, axis_param = list(gp = gpar(fontsize = 12))), col = col_logFC,
              cell_fun = function(j, i, x, y, w, h, col) { # add text to each grid
              grid.text(round(l2_val[i, j],2), x, y)
            }, rect_gp = gpar(col = "white", lwd = 0.11), width = ncol(mat.scaled)*unit(2.8, "mm"), height = nrow(mat.scaled)*unit(2.8, "mm"), show_column_names = F)ype here
```

already tried with: annotation_name_gp = gpar(fontsize = 12)[image]

Comment: solved: I found the answer, I was making a mistake in the parentheses: https://support.bioconductor.org/p/9145229/#9153622